# node js parse excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Right now i have this code:

```
function parseXlsx() {
    console.log(2)
    var XLSX = require('xlsx');
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile('report.xlsx');
    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    var json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet_name_list[1]);
    console.log(json)
}
```

But it consoles empty array `[]`
What do I do?
this is `sheet_name_list`:

```
 [ 'eBook Royalty',
  'KENP Read',
  'Paperback Royalty',
  'Total Royalty' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[1]]);
```